# Two configs for logstash not working together

Tags: logstash-grok, elk

I am having a ELK setup for processing haproxy and nginx logs, for this i have used separate config files for logstash, the main data which i want from logs are the "content url" and the "response time", in haproxy the responsetime is in milliseconds like 1345 and in nginx the response time is in seconds like 1.23. In order to bring the response time in same format i changed the haproxy response time to seconds using ruby plugin in logstash. And i m getting the desired results from both when ran individually, in kibana also i changed the response time field to duration on which input is in seconds and output also in seconds. But when i run both configs together the response time for ngnix logs returns 0.000 value and i can see tag of "_grokparsefailure" in json response, but when i run the ngnix config individually to debug it everything works fine, in kibana dashboard i can see proper response time values.

Below is the config for my Nginx logstash Config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5045
  }
 }


filter {
 grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:content} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:response_bytes:int} \"-\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:junk}\" %{NUMBER:response_time}"}
 }
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        }

}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }

}
```

Below is the config of my Haproxy logstash config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
 }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{MONTH:month}  %{MONTHDAY:date} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:[source]} %{WORD:[app]}\[%{DATA:[class]}\]: %{IPORHOST:[UE_IP]}:%{NUMBER:[UE_Port]} %{IPORHOST:[NATTED_IP]}:%{NUMBER:[NATTED_Source_Port]} %{IPORHOST:[NATTED_IP]}:%{NUMBER:[NATTED_Destination_Port]} %{IPORHOST:[WAN_IP]}:%{NUMBER:[WAN_Port]} \[%{HAPROXYDATE:[timestamp]}\] %{NOTSPACE:[frontend_name]}~ %{NOTSPACE:[backend_name]} %{NOTSPACE:[ty_name]}/%{NUMBER:[response_time]} %{NUMBER:[http_status_code]} %{NUMBER:[response_bytes]:int} - - ---- %{NOTSPACE:[df]} %{NOTSPACE:[df]} %{DATA:[domain_name]} %{DATA:[cache_status]} %{DATA:[domain_name]} %{URIPATHPARAM:[content]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[http_version]}" }

  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
  ruby {
  code => "event.set('response_time', event.get('response_time').to_f / 1000)"
 }
 }

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
  }
```

I m suspecting the response_time pattern ie %{NUMBER:[response_time]} in haproxy and nginx is creating problem. Don't know what is causing this issue tried every possible thing.

Comment: I have one doubt here, whether you are sending both the logstash output to same index in Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Yes I am sending both logstash output to same index